# Can an undirected graph strongly connected?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

From various books and online resources, I've come to know a **directed** graph is said to be **strongly connected** if, all of its vertices reachable from each vertices. 
But my question is, "is it same for the **undirected** graphs also ?"  hence we can visit all vertices of an undirected from graph its each vertices.

Comment: An undirected graph is strongly connected iff it is connected. This is because edges are bidirectional.

Comment: I think @Chrystomath is right, I see it is nonsense to say that an undirected graph is strongly connected.

Comment: @Chrystomath & Fareed AF please see Misha Lavrov's answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an undirected graph, we simply say that it is **connected** when there is a path between any two vertices.

There are then (at least) two ways to generalize this notion to directed graphs:

- **Weakly connected** if there is an undirected path between any two vertices, **not** necessarily respecting the orientations on the edges.
- **Strongly connected** if there is a directed path between any two vertices.

These two definitions have the names they do because strong connectivity implies weak connectivity, but not vice versa. (If, between any two vertices, there is a directed path, it is still a path if we don't care about the orientations.)

In an undirected graph, because there is only one notion of connectivity to begin with, we don't call it strong or weak.

Comment: thanks  
but " strong connectivity implies weak connectivity " I am struggling to understand this line.

Comment: Edited to clarify that. Strong connectivity cares about directions on edges, and weak connectivity doesn't, so if you have the paths needed to satisfy strong connectivity, then those same paths are also going to give you weak connectivity.

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

An undirected graph's edges can be considered bidirectional edges.
Therefore, if all nodes are connected, we can reach from one vertex to any other vertex (as per the definition of a strongly connected graph in directed graphs).
Conversely, if vertices are not connected, it means that a path does not exist between any two pairs of vertices (as per the definition of weakly connected graphs in directed graphs).

Therefore undirected graphs can be considered (Connected Graphs) or (Non-Connected Graphs).